# Laravel Model create not returning primary key on MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I have Model Account, which uses a third-party MS SQL database.
I can create, update and delete accounts, but after a `Account::create(['loginuser' =>'jdoe','loginpwd' => 'supersecret'])` the property "rowguid" is empty.
rowguid is a uniqueidentifier column.

`Account::find('28B7F554-9689-4DFD-9C29-1CDAC6513436')` works.
But I need the rowguid after creation, to store it in another Model as property.

So I tried to "create" manually

```php
$conn = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->getPdo();
$sqlString = "DECLARE @lastinsertid TABLE (rowguid uniqueidentifier);INSERT INTO dbo.accounts (loginuser,loginpwd) OUTPUT INSERTED.rowguid INTO @lastinsertid VALUES (?,?);SELECT rowguid FROM @lastinsertid;";
$sqlVals = ['jdoe','supersecret'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlString);
$stmt->execute($sqlVals);
$temp = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This results in:

**PDOException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.'**

Running this on SQL Studio works and returns rowguid:

```sql
DECLARE @lastinsertid TABLE (rowguid uniqueidentifier);
INSERT INTO accounts (loginuser,loginpwd) OUTPUT INSERTED.rowguid INTO @lastinsertid VALUES ('johndoe','supersecret');
SELECT rowguid FROM @lastinsertid;
```

I'm using Laravel 8.32.1 with PHP 8.0.3 on linux with msodbcsql17-17.7.2.1-1

Comment: Would using a Trait like the one shown here work? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/using-uuid-for-the-id-and-getting-it-returned-after-create-or-save?page=1#reply=660334

Comment: give this a try by using lastInsertId() method

$lastId = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

Comment: @hppycoder thx, the Trait does work!

Comment: @PatrickHeppler so happy to hear that! I have put this as a formal answer to help others who come across StackOverflow looking for the same thing. I'm not sure if Tippin is on here (I assume they are) but I appreciate the work they did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this to a formal answer because the link on [laracasts - Using uuid for the id and getting it returned after Create or Save](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/using-uuid-for-the-id-and-getting-it-returned-after-create-or-save?page=1#reply=660334) could potentially change and the answer was found through the comments.

Tippin shows how to use the following Trait because Laravel merged the Ramsey package into `Str::class` facade. This to solve the issue with UUID + SQL Server.

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Str;

trait Uuids
{
    /**
     * On model creating, set the primary key to UUID
     */
    public static function bootUuids()
    {
        static::creating(function (Model $model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Str::orderedUuid()->toString();
        });
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
$test = User::create([
    'first' => 'Derpy',
    'last' => 'Herpy',
    'slug' => '12345',
    'active' => 1,
    'email' => 'ok@ok.com',
    'password' => 'password'
]);

dump($test->id);

//"91e85023-4508-4c90-972b-5298e1768702"

$test2 = new User();
$test2->first = 'nope';
$test2->last = 'never';
$test2->slug = '8888';
$test2->active = 1;
$test2->email = 'whyr@lolol.com';
$test2->password = '987987987';
$test2->save();

dump($test2->id);

//"91e85023-55a7-46e0-801c-8fa9ed9a846a"
```